# Линейная регрессия ошибка в построение модели

Tags: python, statsmodels

код работает

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys


def my_code(series, n):
    array_sl = [j * 0 for j in range(n - 1)]

    for j in range(n, len(series) + 1):
        y = series[j - n:j]
        x = np.array(range(n))
        x_sc = (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
        y_sc = (y - y.min()) / (y.max() - y.min())
        x_sc = sm.add_constant(x_sc)
        model = sm.OLS(y_sc, x_sc)
        try:
            results = model.fit()
        except Exception:
            print(sys.exc_info()[1].args[0])
        array_sl.append(results.params[-1])
    slope_angle = (np.rad2deg(np.arctan(np.array(array_sl))))
    return np.array(slope_angle)


s = [0.5763, 0.5764, 0.5776, 0.5776, 0.5777, 0.5758, 0.5782, 0.5746, 0.5732, 0.5733, 0.5739, 0.5736, 0.5732, 0.5729,
     0.5716, 0.5699, 0.5699, 0.5702, 0.5693, 0.5699, 0.5712, 0.5715, 0.5674, 0.5649, 0.5648, 0.5656, 0.5663, 0.5656,
     0.5643, 0.5636, 0.5658, 0.5663, 0.5678, 0.567, 0.5664, 0.5645, 0.5647, 0.5654, 0.5653, 0.5605, 0.5657, 0.5672,
     0.5683, 0.568, 0.5669, 0.5659, 0.5663, 0.5665, 0.5655, 0.5665, 0.5673, 0.5678, 0.5685, 0.5673, 0.5665, 0.5683,
     0.5686, 0.5673, 0.5654, 0.5626, 0.5583, 0.5586, 0.5595, 0.5612, 0.5601, 0.5588, 0.5543, 0.556, 0.5536, 0.5525,
     0.5433, 0.5414, 0.539, 0.5383, 0.5394, 0.5397, 0.5375, 0.5318, 0.5333, 0.5346, 0.5323, 0.5267, 0.5247, 0.5265,
     0.5222, 0.5236, 0.5251, 0.5255, 0.5273, 0.5249, 0.5278, 0.5274, 0.5277, 0.5277, 0.5263, 0.5249, 0.5255, 0.523,
     0.5294, 0.533]

ss = pd.Series(s)
print(my_code(ss, 5))
```

но когда хочу пройтись по шагам в debug PyCharm возникает исключение на строчке:

```
results = model.fit()
```

и выдает ошибку 'NoneType' object is not callable
а когда просто запускаю, все отлично, выдает результат
в чем может быть загвоздка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запустил в Spyder. В режиме пошаговой отладки.  Все работает как часики.  Ну и кроме того, я на скрине вижу Warning, а не ошибку.  Т.е. как бы вас предупредили, но работа должна быть продолжена.

Comment: Warning - это ругает версия Pycharm. ее исправил! Установил новую виртуалку, поставил новый python 3.10, pycharm 2022.1, больше ни чего ! все равно при запуске код работает а вот debug вылетает!